# Direct XML output to different client in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, printing

I have an xml enabled label printer that will respond to a specific xml stream.  I've created the appropriate view/routing in Rails to produce the XML, but the XML is always sent back to my browser, even if I change @_request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'].  What I need is the XML sent to the printer.

Is there a trivial way to do this, or am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: Rails responds to the client. If you want to make a request to a different device, use nethttp or one of its wrappers.

Comment: However, I want to respond to a different device, not make a request to it.

Comment: No, you want to send XML to a different client. That's making a request. And you *still* need to respond to the original requesting client so they know what happened. So yes, IMO you're approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: You're right, I do want to let the original client know how things worked out.  I'm looking through the nethttp library and I'd take any advice on how to do what you suggested.  I attempted send_request, which takes a data string, but doesn't take a URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to what I was trying to achieve (vs. what I asked) lies in the socket library within Ruby.  I needed to simply open a tcp socket to the printer (to the RAW port), then perform a puts of the xml string that I needed to send:

```
data = 'xml stream goes here'
hostip = '10.3.1.40'
port = 9100
labelPrinter = TCPSocket.open(hostip, port)
labelPrinter.puts(data)
labelPrinter.close
```

And the rest works as expected.

Comment: Once I had a sense of what I was after, I was able to find a bit of sample code on the Zebra site in C# that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

use the STDLIB of ruby http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP

or one of those many http libs available for ruby: http://bit.ly/RNCClq

Comment: Well, I think this is the right answer (as Dave said as well).  Right now I can't get a response out of the printer, and the documentation is weak enough that I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.  The console is giving me a Net::HTTPNotImplemented response, and I'm not sure why, the printer certainly does have it implemented.

Comment: did ever successfully talk to the printer via http? with curl or wget or something?

Comment: @JeffreyAlanLee Perhaps you're making the wrong type of request.

Comment: @DaveNewton, you nailed that one.  Sometimes I just need to smack my head against something to realize that I was not thinking about it correctly.

Comment: @JeffreyAlanLee I have a lot of experience not thinking about things correctly ;)